# A sample https client request c++ program to invoke using gsoap

Tags: visual-c++, gsoap

I got HTTP_SSL_ERROR code value 30 even after adding the CA certificate, while invoking the web service using gSOAP.

Answer (score 0):

Proxy class which is generated provides the cafile and ssl_flag, so we can pass the certificate that verifies the certificate in https like this :

```
 BindingProxy *Service = new BindingPRoxy();
 Service->cafile = "C:\\Users\\Machinename\\Desktop\\ca.cer";
 Service->ssl_flags = SOAP_SSL_DEFAULT;
```

This will verify the SSL certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the gsoap sample programs in your installation directory. You may find more detail on this issue.

```
if (soap_ssl_client_context(&soap,
    /* SOAP_SSL_NO_AUTHENTICATION, */ /* for encryption w/o authentication */
    /* SOAP_SSL_DEFAULT | SOAP_SSL_SKIP_HOST_CHECK, */  /* if we don't want the host name checks since these will change from machine to machine */
    SOAP_SSL_DEFAULT,   /* use SOAP_SSL_DEFAULT in production code */
    NULL,       /* keyfile (cert+key): required only when client must authenticate to server (see SSL docs to create this file) */
    NULL,       /* password to read the keyfile */
    "cacert.pem",   /* optional cacert file to store trusted certificates, use cacerts.pem for all public certificates issued by common CAs */
    NULL,       /* optional capath to directory with trusted certificates */
    NULL        /* if randfile!=NULL: use a file with random data to seed randomness */ 
  ))
  { soap_print_fault(&soap, stderr);
    exit(1);
  }
```